# Django, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nombre' referenced before assignment in view.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

im having a problem with a with a post request of a form, this is how the models.py is:

```
class Invitaciones(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitaciones"

    tipos_cedula = (
        ("Venezolano", "Venezolano"),
        ("Extranjero", "Extranjero"),
    )
    estados = (
        ("Disponible", "Disponible"),
        ("Usado", "Usado"),
    )
    def random_string():
        return str(random.randint(10000, 99999))

    año = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    tipo_cedula = models.CharField(choices=tipos_cedula, max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    cedula = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=99999999, default = random_string, null=False, blank=False, editable=False)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=estados, default="Disponible", null=False, blank=False)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(datetime.date(año, 12, 31),message="No puedes elegir una fecha que este mas alla de este año"), validators.MinValueValidator(datetime.date.today(),message="No puedes elegir una fecha anterior a la de hoy")])
    envio = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.usuario, self.nombres, self.apellidos, self.cedula, self.codigo,)
```

And this is how the views.py is:

```
    from cuentas.models import Invitaciones
    from cuentas.forms import InvitacionesForm
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse, render_to_response

class InvitacionesView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'socios/pases.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = InvitacionesForm()
        invitaciones = Invitaciones.objects.all()

        args = {'form': form, 'titulo': 'Pases de Invitación', 'invitaciones': invitaciones}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):

        form = InvitacionesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre']  
            apellido = form.cleaned_data['apellido']  
            tipo_cedula = form.cleaned_data['tipo_cedula']
            cedula = form.cleaned_data['cedula']
            fecha = form.cleaned_data['fecha']
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.usuario_id = post.user.id
            post.save()
            form = InvitacionesForm()
            messages.success(request, 'El pase de invitación a sido registrado.')
            return redirect('pases')
        else:    
            messages.error(request, 'Por favor, verifica tus datos') 
            form = InvitacionesForm()
            return redirect('pases')

        args = {'form': form, 'nombre': nombre, 'apellido': apellido, 'tipo_cedula': tipo_cedula, 'fecha': fecha, 'cedula': cedula, 'estado': estado,}  
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kuipumu\Desktop\Oricao\dist\cuentas\views.py", line 122, in post
    args = {'form': form, 'nombre': nombre, 'apellido': apellido, 'tipo_cedula': tipo_cedula, 'fecha': fecha, 'cedula': cedula, 'estado': estado,}UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nombre' referenced before assignment
```

I can't find why im getting this error, i made the model, view, and form based on another model, view and form that is already perfectly working. The object can be registered thought the admin view, but not trought the user view. ¿Why im getting this local variable error?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def post(self, request):

        form = InvitacionesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre']  
            apellido = form.cleaned_data['apellido']  
            tipo_cedula = form.cleaned_data['tipo_cedula']
            cedula = form.cleaned_data['cedula']
            fecha = form.cleaned_data['fecha']
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.usuario_id = post.user.id
            post.save()
            form = InvitacionesForm()
            messages.success(request, 'El pase de invitación a sido registrado.')
            return redirect('pases')
        else:    
            messages.error(request, 'Por favor, verifica tus datos') 
            form = InvitacionesForm()
            return redirect('pases')

        args = {'form': form}  
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

you cant access the fields inside the `form.valid()` like that outside,

Comment: Yes, that deleted the error, thought now im having another error. I have another form with these fields declared like that and it works, just the exact same thing, i don't understand why.

Comment: if you need to access those fields you need to put the args inside the if form.is_valid()

Comment: If args is put inside form.is_valid() the same error appears.

Comment: it wont, if you dont have mismatching variable in the args, match the names and check

Comment: The match but the error its not the variables inside args but args itself i get  
local variable 'args' referenced before assignment

Comment: the answer i provided, you should use it like that